# Python: Remove values from dictionary value list if the value exist in longer key in the dict

Tags: python

I have a dict like this:

```
{'key1':['val1','val2','val3'], 'key1_key2':['val1','val3','val4']}
```

I want to remove redundancy, for each value, if the value is also a value of a different key with a longer word, remove the value from the shorter word key.

So in this example, the output would be:

```
{'key1':['val2'],'key1_key2':['val1','val3','val4']}
```

I'm looking for the most pythonic way to do this. I know one way that I could develop is:

```
#for each key and value in the dict
for k,v in dict1.items():
        #so i can compare to every other key and value in the dict
        for k2,v2 in dict1.items():
                #if k2 string is a subset of k string (i.e. if one k is 'key1' and one k is 'key1_key2'):
                        small_list = #remove any item that's also in the big list
                        dict1[k] = small_list
```

I'm wondering is this the best way to develop this (before I get dragged down in trying to get this to work) or does someone have a better solution.

Comment: And what should be the result for this dict `{'key1'['val1','val2','val3'],'key1_key2':['val1','val3','val4'], 'key3_key2_key1': ['val1']}` ???

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I believe the output should be  `{'key1'['val2'],'key1_key2':['val3','val4'], 'key3_key2_key1': ['val1']}`

Comment: @RaySteam, not much. How about this `{'key1': ['val1','val2','val3'],'key1_key2':['val1','val3','val4', 'val2'], 'key3_key1_key2': ['val1']}` ? (the keys were changed)

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest What do you mean by the keys were changed? IMHO what the OP wants if just leave the value in longest key (longest by len).

Comment: @RaySteam, compare the input dict from my 1st and last comment and see the difference. I'm not posting my comments "just for fun" - we need to know the edge cases

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest For your second input the output should be: `{'key1': [],'key1_key2':['val3','val4', 'val2'], 'key3_key1_key2': ['val1']}`

Comment: As RaySteam said, i really just want to remove duplicates from the dictionary, by assigning each value to the longest key string; so '{'key1'['val2'],'key1_key2':['val3','val4'], 'key3_key2_key1': ['val1']}'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = {'key1': ['val1', 'val2', 'val3'], 'key1_key2': ['val1', 'val3', 'val4']}

longest_key = defaultdict(str)

# create a dictionary that maps values to the longest key
for key, values in d.items():
    for value in values:
        longest_key[value] = max(longest_key[value], key, key=len)

# filter out the input dictionary using the lookup dictionary created in the above step
for key, values in d.items():
    d[key] = [value for value in values if longest_key[value] == key]

print(d)
```

**Output**

```
{'key1': ['val2'], 'key1_key2': ['val1', 'val3', 'val4']}
```